# Have 2 Spotify api calls, how can I put them into 1 Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, promise, request

I want to make these 2 spotify api calls just once in my multi page react app. I want to pass these props to the Phases component. I want to be able to fetch the response data in 1 fetch call if that is possible like using Promise.all(). But I can't figure out how to do this with these api calls. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from './components/SelectPage/Home';
import Phases from './components/PhasePage/Phases';
import About from './components/AboutPage/About';
import Auth from './components/Login/Auth';

import { 
    BrowserRouter as Router, 
    Route, 
} from 'react-router-dom'; 

var Spotify = require('spotify-web-api-js');
var spotifyApi = new Spotify();

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    const params = this.getHashParams(); //tokens saved here
    if (params.access_token && params.refresh_token) {
      window.localStorage.setItem('spotifyToken', params.access_token);
      window.localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', params.refresh_token); 
    }    
    this.state = {
      loggedIn: window.localStorage.getItem('spotifyToken') ? true : false,
      artistsLoaded: false,
      tracksLoaded: false,
      top_artists_ids: [],
      top_tracks_ids: [],
      artist_items : [],
      track_items : []
    };   
  }
  
    componentDidMount(){
      if (window.localStorage.getItem('spotifyToken')){
          spotifyApi.
          setAccessToken(window.localStorage.getItem('spotifyToken'));
          this.spotifyGetTopTrackIds();
          this.spotifyGetTopArtistIds();
       }
    }

    spotifyGetTopTrackIds = () => {
        spotifyApi.getMyTopTracks({ time_range: "long_term",limit: 50})
        .then((data) => {
            var track_ids = data.items.map(function (obj) {
                return obj.id;
            });
            this.setState({
              track_items: data.items,
              top_tracks_ids: track_ids,
              tracksLoaded: true
            })
        },
        function (err) {
            Error();
            console.error(err);
        });
      }
  
      spotifyGetTopArtistIds = () => {
          spotifyApi.getMyTopArtists({ time_range: "long_term", limit: 50})
          .then((data) => {
              var artist_ids = data.items.map(function (obj) {
                  return obj.id;
              });
    
              this.setState({
                artist_items: data.items,
                top_artists_ids: artist_ids,
                artistsLoaded: true
              })
            }, 
            function (err) {
                Error();
                console.error(err);
            });
      }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.artistsLoaded || !this.state.tracksLoaded){
      return <div> Loading...</div>
    }
    return (
        <Router>
          {this.state.loggedIn
            ?
              <div className='App'>
                <Route exact path = '/home' component= {Home}/>
                <Route exact path= '/phases' 
                  render={(props) => 
                  <Phases 
                    top_tracks_ids={this.state.top_tracks_ids} 
                    top_artists_ids={this.state.top_artists_ids}
                    artist_items={this.state.artist_items}
                    track_items={this.state.track_items}
                    {...props}/>}
                  />
                <Route exact path= '/about' component = {About}/>
                <Route exact path= '/' component = {Auth}/>
              </div>
            :<Route path= '/' component = {Auth}/>
        }
        </Router>
    ); 
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this example helps you to unterstand how to use `Promise.all`

```js
function getSpotifyData() {
  const topTracksPromise = spotifyApi.getMyTopTracks({ time_range: 'long_term', limit: 50 })
  const topArtistsPromise = spotifyApi.getMyTopArtists({ time_range: 'long_term', limit: 50 })

  Promise.all([topTracksPromise, topArtistsPromise]).then(([topTracks, topArtists]) => {
    const track_ids = topTracks.items.map((obj) => obj.id)
    const artist_ids = topArtists.items.map((obj) => obj.id)

    // set state etc.
  })
}
```

However, I prefer async/await :

```js
async function getSpotifyData() {
  const topTracks = await spotifyApi.getMyTopTracks({ time_range: 'long_term', limit: 50 })
  const topArtists = await spotifyApi.getMyTopArtists({ time_range: 'long_term', limit: 50 })

  const trackIds = topTracks.items.map((obj) => obj.id)
  const artistIds = topArtists.items.map((obj) => obj.id)

  // set state etc.
}
```

Do not forget to put this inside a `try/catch` - or add a `.catch()` respectively.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much it works perfectly and makes the code so much more readable. This is obvious but I should probably put this in a try catch statement right? And then call my refresh token function in the catch statement as I'd need to probably refresh the api token if there is a response error as I did in the previous functions.

Comment: Happy to help :) Yes, you should put the async function inside a try/catch (and add a .catch() for the other one), I forgot to mention that but will update my answer! Inside the catch block you could check the error code or message to decide whether you should refresh the auth tokens or do something else.

Comment: Last question, sorry! Do i put the try catch inside the getSpotifyData function or do I put it where I call it (inside componentDidMount). I would think inside the getspotifyData function itself.

Comment: Since the `getSpotifyData()` is an `async` function, it (implicitly) returns a Promise. So you would wrap the whole function inside a `try/catch`- for example in the `componentDidMount` or wherever else you call it :)